# Using Firebase for Authentication PostegreSQL db

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently working on a react application, and have a database of customer information. I want to turn that information into accounts, and was wondering if Firebase will work for this? I don't want to have to store passwords, or deal with accounts, so I just want current customers to be able to log in with google / facebook. Will Firebase be able to link into my current PostgreSQL db, or how would that work?

There are NPM modules for this that I have been looking into, however I was wondering if Firebase is a better option for this. Also, what would the limitations of a free Firebase account be?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication has no built-in connection to PostgreSQL.

But if you have a trusted environment where you can run code (like your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions for Firebase), you can use the Firebase Admin SDK to verify the token from Firebase Authentication. For more on this approach, see the Firebase documentation on [verifying ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).